# Как сделать авторизацию через google?

Tags: android, google-play

Как сделать авторизацию через google в своем android приложении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот [тут](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/) полностью описано как сделать авторизацию через Google и с возможностью скачать код.